# httr::oauth1.0_token error with twitter api

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, proxy, httr

I'm currently trying to interact with Twitter's Streaming API via the httr package:

```
library(httr)
my_app <- oauth_app('twitter', consumerKey, consumerSecret)
twitter_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints('twitter'), my_app)
```

This brings up the following question and error:

```
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No
Selection: 2
Error in init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = params$permission) : 
  client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a proxy problem and more likely to be a misconfiguration of your app settings. It usually means you've forgotten to set the callback url to http://localhost:1410

Comment: @hadley - you're a genius! That completely fixed the problem, so if you'd like to post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Will do. I took the liberty of removing the extranous info from your question so others will more easily see if they're having the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever have problems with twitter OAuth, first check that the callback url is `http://localhost:1410`